# Что означает восклицательный знак "!" в выражении?

Tags: typescript

Просто это выражение я понимаю, а что за восклицательные знаки здесь?

```typescript
block.firstElementChild!.setAttribute(
  'data-id',
  tgt.getAttribute('data-id')!
);
```

Или такой код:

```typescript
[...set!].map (() => {do smth})
```

Comment: автор, пожалуйста, если руки дойдут, пометьте ответ @UserTest013 принятым

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Согласно документации, [Non-Null Assertion Operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#non-null-assertion-operator-postfix-) указывает компилятору [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript), что свойство перед знаком восклицания не `null` и не `undefined`.

Как и другие утверждения типов, это не меняет поведение вашего кода во время выполнения, поэтому важно использовать `!` только в том случае, если вы **знаете**, что значение не может быть `null` или `undefined`.

```typescript
function liveDangerously(x?: number | null) {
  // No error
  console.log(x!.toFixed());
}
```

Разумно использовать оператор `!` тогда, когда вы **уверены**, что переменная никогда не станет `null`, или `undefined`, - просто уверены, и вам надо, чтобы код работал и компилировался без всяких проверок.